# What is the exact timeline of "the machine" and its plans, and is there more than one?

Tags: dark

Minor spoilers ahead.

I know about [this page](https://www.dark.netflix.io/time-machine). It has a (hi)story of "the machine". But it leaves out some details and is not straight forward.
I have the impression that there are some "gaps" in the timeline of the machine and that sometimes there is at least one more instance around than there should be.

So my concrete questions about "the machine":

1. Who draw the plans for it in the first place?
2. Are all the instances of the machine we see throughout the series one and the same machine?
3. If there is more than one machine, who build the other one(s)?
4. If it's all one machine, could anybody give a complete timeline of it?

While my impression was that there is only one machine, with a very complex timeline, the *Dark* website seems to imply that there is more than one. And it also fails to present one closed timeline. It looks as if there were more than one machine.

Edit:

The answer to 1. seems to be Jonas/Adam. Of course inspired by the machine itself (bootstrap paradoxon). The plans where taken by "The Unknown(s)" from the abandoned Sic Mundus headquarters, brought to Eve who gave it to Claudia who gave it to Tannhaus.

The answer of 2. seems to be YES, by some youtube videos which claim this information comes from an interview with the creators. (Sadly can't find it again). If thats true, 3. is obsolete.

For 4. there are many efforts that culminate all in the same problems. All can track 2 timelines. All have 2 Gaps. There are two instances of the machine end up in the Sic Mundus Headquarter. One of them must find it's way to Noah (who gave it to Bartosz), the other one must find it's way to Claudia. There seems to be no information about how this two things happen. Also unexplained is, who and when "optimized" the machine, that it no longer needs a smartphone to activate.

Comment: Exact timeline would take time, but the answer to the first question is Claudia. Claudia exists in the original timeline and she is well versed with physics.

Comment: @C.Koca - There's no reason to think the machine was ever designed in the original timeline. In the series we saw Eva gave the blueprints to the time machine to Claudia right after Claudia killed her double from Eva's universe (scene starts about 31 minutes into ep. 7 of season 3), and the opening scene of episode 1 of season 3 shows the Unknown trio burning Sic Mundus and taking the blueprints, suggesting it was designed at Sic Mundus by Adam and/or Noah (Adam also had a wall with schematics of different machines that he showed to Jonas in episode 5 of season 2, a little over 41 mins. in)

Comment: On #2, [here is an interview with the creators](https://www.vulture.com/2019/06/dark-netflix-season-two-time-travel-interview.html) where Baran Bo Odar says: *The thing is, it’s only one machine, it just comes with different patina levels. Sometimes it’s older or younger or broken, but it’s only one machine. And that’s where people get confused. I remember many, many discussions with actors that were like, “But no, aren’t there like three machines?” No, it’s the same machine!*